# How can I convert between Float and [Word8]?

Tags: haskell

I want to convert Float to a list of bytes [Word8] (and vice versa). I see there is a Storable class which could maybe be used for this, but I'd like to avoid using IO monad as this has nothing to do with IO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is it that you want? If you want to convert between the Float and its actual bit representation, you can use [data-binary-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754) (uses `Foreign.Storable` and `unsafePerformIO` under the hood) or [cereal-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-ieee754). The latter doesn't use `Storable` or `IO`, it writes the value to an `STUArray`, casts the array and reads a value of the other type. Both packages give you a conversion `Float <-> Word32` (or `Double <-> Word64`), converting the `WordN` to `[Word8]` is easy.

Comment: cereal-ieee754 belongs now to cereal.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, the conversion functions are no longer exported.

Comment: Surely you can build the conversions yourself by processing the resulting ByteString? There'll be a performance loss, though...

Comment: @ehird Sure one can do that. And if the target is indeed `[Word8]`, not much is lost, but if one wants to convert `Double <-> Word64`, it's nice to have the conversion ready-made (in addition to the performance aspect).

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the [`Data.Binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.4.1/doc/html/Data-Binary.html) library.

See here:

```
Prelude Data.Binary> encode (13.7 :: Double)
Chunk "\SOH\SOH\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\affffff\ESC\255\255\255\255\255\255\255\207" Empty
Prelude Data.Binary Data.ByteString.Lazy> Data.ByteString.Lazy.unpack $ encode (13.7 :: Double)
[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,102,102,102,102,102,102,27,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,207]
```

If you're wondering why the representation is that big, it's because of the implementation of the `Binary` instance for `Float` and `Double` uses `decodeFloat` function:

```
decodeFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> (Integer, Int)
```

This is done to keep the implementation as generic as the Haskell Report (which doesn't specify IEEE754 or anything like that).

To get the actual binary representation of a `Float`, you need to use `Storable` AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want Storable you want Binary.  See the [binary package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.5.0.2).

The Float and Double instances use the prelude "encodeFloat" and "decodeFloat" functions, as these are an implementation-independent way of converting between a floating point value and a pair of integers.  The two integers are then converted to bytes.